# Can't get html to check value

Tags: javascript, html

I am having my webpage get the value of a textbox and check it to a value of "bypass".  If the stuff in the textbox equals the value of "bypass", then the website will redirect to google.  But it doesn't work, even if you put in the correct values.

My Code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>ACA2</title>
  </head>



<body>
<center>
  <form>
    <p><input type="password" name="pass"><br></p>
    <p><button onclick="bypassCheck()">...</button></p>
  </form>
    <p><a href="index.html">Back</a></p>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bypassCheck() {
  var aaa = document.getElementByName('pass')[0].value
  var bbb = "bypass";
  if(aaa == bbb) {
    window.location.assign("www.google.com")
  }
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using the HTML5 doctype. The `<center>` element does not exist in HTML5. Wrap it in a different element (e.g. `<section>` or `<div>`) and using CSS set this to `text-align: center;`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that wasn't the issue.  My issue was the values won't check.

Comment: @butenhjo2018 That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: `getElementByName` is not a function. Eighter use getElementsByName or (in your case more appropiate) `getElementById`. But then you'd have to give your input an id

Comment: Typo question, correct function is `getElementsByName` - elements in the plural. Voting to close.

Comment: @butenhjo2018 I didn't say that was the issue, I was just pointing out something invalid with your code.

Comment: Learn how to debug JavaScript so that you can help yourself: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: @butenhjo2018, You should learn about your browsers developer tools and use the Javascript console. You would have seen the simple syntax error and solved this in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use document.getElementsByName and window.open("https://www.google.co.in/") with proper https URL. If you provide only www.google.co.in then you won't be redirected to google.

Below is the working code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <title>ACA2</title>
      </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <form>
        <p><input type="password" name="pass"><br></p>
        <p><button onclick="bypassCheck()">...</button></p>
      </form>
        <p><a href="index.html">Back</a></p>
    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function bypassCheck() {
     var aaa = document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value
      var bbb = "bypass";
      if(aaa == bbb) {
        window.open("https://www.google.co.in/")
      }
    }
    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that it's not getElementByName, but getElementsByName, as in plural. So it would be:

```
  var aaa = document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value
```